# Pig : parsing line with blank delimiter

Tags: apache-pig

I'm using Hadoop Pig (0.10.0) to process logs file, a log line looking like :

```
2012-08-01  INFO   (User:irim)   getListedStocksByMarkets completed in 7041 ms
```

I would like to get a relation with tokens split by blanks, that is :

`(2012-08-01,INFO,(User:irim),getListedStocksByMarkets,completed,in,7041,ms`)

Loading that data with statement :

`records = LOAD 'myapp.log' using PigStorage(' ');`

did not achieve that because my tokens can be separated by several white space leading to several empty tokens. 
PigStorage does not seem to support regexp delimiter (or at least I haven't succeeded configuring it that way).

So my question : what would be the best way to get those tokens ?

If I could remove empty elements from a relation I would be happy, is possible to do that with Pig ?

For example starting from :

`(2012-08-01,,,INFO,,,(User:irim),,getListedStocksByMarkets,completed,in,7041,ms`)

To get

`(2012-08-01,INFO,(User:irim),getListedStocksByMarkets,completed,in,7041,ms`)

I'm trying another approach with `TextLoader` then `TOKENIZE` but I'm not sure it's the best strategy. 
Maybe a User Load Function is a more natural choice ...

Regards,

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built in function STRSPLIT with regular expression to break a line into a tuple. Here is a script for your particular example with comma as a separator:

```
inpt = load '~/data/regex.txt' as (line : chararray);
dump inpt;
-- 2012-08-01,,,INFO,,,(User:irim),,getListedStocksByMarkets,completed,in,7041,ms

splt = foreach inpt generate flatten(STRSPLIT(line, ',+'));
dump splt;
-- (2012-08-01,INFO,(User:irim),getListedStocksByMarkets,completed,in,7041,ms)
```

Comment: It works, thank you !

I tend to think that a User Load Function would be more efficient, do you agree with that ?

Comment: Yes, it will. The benifits are: separation of data format from the pig script, integration with AS (columns ......).